# CSS image in percentage sized container

Tags: css, image, layout, aspect-ratio

I have the following code:

https://codepen.io/rctneil/pen/NWwGQyr?editors=1100

Basically my issue revolves around the `.card-logo` elements.

I will be putting a variety of logo images in this location.  I need them to be a maximum width of 50% of the parent card and a maximum height of 50% of the width of the parent card.

That itself wouldn't be too difficult, but I also need them to be less than that if the aspect of the image requires it.  Eg, if it's a portrait image then the height should be 50% of the width of the card but the width of the logo needs to just be whatever it ends up being naturally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `margin: 25%;` on the image or `padding: 25%;` on the container, because those are always relative to the container width - even the top and bottom ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution : https://codepen.io/Woralie/pen/dyZvzRP

You'll need to add a container for each logo image.

```
  .card-logo {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0.75rem;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    background-color: white;
  }

  .card-logo-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -25%;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    padding: 25%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
```

The trick is to make the container `position: relative` with `padding: 25%` and the image `position: absolute` with `max-width: 50%`. The container's top and bottom paddings take 2*25% of the total width, so when its height is 0, the image's height at `max-height: 100%` takes a maximum of 50% of the container's total width.

Comment: Ah!  Looks interesting.  I'll hopefully take a proper look and test it out in place later tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Made a few alterations but used it on my site here: https://neiltonge.co.uk/parks/coasters.   Feel free to take a look.  The images are all so odd that I had to come up with some standard way of housing them.  I still have to edit some as some look very uneven!  But thanks for your help.